# Вернуть подстроки из строки через пробел и с большой буквы каждое слово

Tags: python, строки

нужно написать функцию, которая будет искать совпадения в строке и возвращать их отсортированными с большой буквы  и через пробел.

например, есть строка `"cokefriessandwichpizzaburgercoke"`

нужно вернуть `"Burger Fries Pizza Sandwich Coke Coke"`. Порядок слов в соответствии к меню:

> ```
> Burger
> Fries
> Chicken
> Pizza
> Sandwich
> Onionrings
> Milkshake
> Coke
> ```

```
def get_order(order: str) -> str:
    menu = "Burger", "Fries", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Sandwich", "Onionrings", "Milkshake", "Coke"
    result = ""
    for i in menu:
        if i.lower() > 1 in order:
            result += i + " "
    return result

если слово в строке повторяется, то нужно вывести все такие слова
```

Comment: Все дополнения вносите в сам вопрос. Также рекомендую почитать справку по оформлению: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help В метках вопроса в первую очередь укажите язык программирования.

Answer (score 3):

Разбиваете задачу на шаги и решаете. Это называется "декомпозиция задачи". Что нужно сделать:

- Найти одно из слов списка меню начиная с начала строки, для этого нужно перебрать слова из списка и найти подходящее слово. На каждой итерации цикла:

  - Взять срез из строки, длиной как очередное слово списка
  - Сравнить этот срез с этим словом, приведя слова к одному регистру
  - Если слова совпали

    - Добавить это слово в выходной список
    - Сдвинуться по обрабатываемой строке на длину найденного слова
    - Прервать цикл по списку (вернее - начать поиск с начала списка)
- Делать так, пока строка поиска не кончится
- Вывести список найденных слов через пробел

Программу пишите сами - ведь это задание для вас. Там будут ещё тонкости. Но общую схему рассуждений я вам показал.

Comment: def get_order(order: str) -> str:
    menu = "Burger", "Fries", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Sandwich", "Onionrings", "Milkshake", "Coke"
    result = ""
    for i in menu:
        if order[:len(i)].lower() == i.lower():
            order = order -i
            result += i      
    return result

Comment: как сдвинуться по строке дальше?

Comment: `order = order[len(i):]`

Comment: def get_order(order: str) -> str:
#     menu = "Burger", "Fries", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Sandwich", "Onionrings", "Milkshake", "Coke"
#     result = ""
#     for i in menu:
#         if i.lower() in order:
#             result += i + " "
#     return result

Comment: сделал по-другому. выводит все хорошо. но если елемент повторяется - то выводит только один раз. а надо все..

Comment: например:
cokefriessandwichcoke = Fries Sandwich Coke Coke